# Tensorflow - stop restoring network parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm attempting to make multiple sequential predictions from a tensorflow network, but performance seems very poor (~500ms per prediction for a 2-layer 8x8 convolutional network) even for a CPU.  I suspect that part of the problem is that it appears to be reloading the network parameters every time.  Each call to `classifier.predict` in the code below results in the following line of output - which I therefore see hundreds of times.

`INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/model_data/model.ckpt-102001`

**How can I reuse the checkpoint that is already loaded?**

(I can't do batch predictions here because the output of the network is a move to play in a game, which then needs to be applied to the current state before feeding the the new game state.)

Here's the loop that's doing the predictions.

```
def rollout(classifier, state):
  while not state.terminated:
    predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": state.as_nn_input()}, shuffle=False)
    prediction = next(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))
    index = np.random.choice(NUM_ACTIONS, p=prediction["probabilities"]) # Select a move according to the network's output probabilities
    state.apply_move(index)
```

`classifier` is a `tf.estimator.Estimator` created with...

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'model_data'))
```

Comment: I am having the same trouble, please someone helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Estimator API](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators) is a high-level API.

> The tf.estimator framework makes it easy to construct and train
>   machine learning models via its high-level Estimator API. Estimator
>   offers classes you can instantiate to quickly configure common model
>   types such as regressors and classifiers.

The Estimator API abstracts away lots of the complexity of TensorFlow, but loses some generality in the process.  Having read the code, it's clear that there's no way to run multiple sequential predictions without reloading the model each time.  The low-level TensorFlow APIs allow this behaviour.  But...

[Keras](https://keras.io/) is a high-level framework that supports this use case.  Simple [define the model](https://keras.io/models/model/) and then call [`predict`](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict) repeatedly.

```
def rollout(model, state):
  while not state.terminated:
    predictions = model.predict(state.as_nn_input())
    for _, prediction in enumerate(predictions):
      index = np.random.choice(bt.ACTIONS, p=prediction)
      state.apply_mode(index)
```

Unscientific benchmarking shows that this is ~100x faster.